# Find Function in VBA (Excel) won't find the minimum value

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying this a lot of times but I don't get this working. 
What I want to achieve: Find the minimum value in a specific column F:F and then get me the row number (or range address) where this value is.

Note: Variable `rngMinimumVariableEins` has to be reformat because the value is very small.

```
Dim rngMinimumVariableEinsWert As Range
Dim strResultValue As String
Dim rngMinimumVariableEins As Range

Set rngMinimumVariableEins = Worksheets("Berechnung").Range("F:F")
rngMinimumVariableEins.NumberFormat = "0.00000000000000000000000000"
strResultValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(rngMinimumVariableEins)
Debug.Print strResultValue

Set rngMinimumVariableEinsWert = rngMinimumVariableEins.Find(strResultValue, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
If rngMinimumVariableEinsWert Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "No Results"
Else
    Debug.Print rngMinimumVariableEinsWert.Row
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel worksheets have a 15 significant digit floating point limit and you can **never** reliably find a string that looks like a number in a column of true numbers.

```
dim minpos as variant

with Worksheets("Berechnung").range("F:F")
    minpos = application.match(application.min(.cells.value2), .cells, 0)
end with

If iserror(minpos) Then
    Debug.Print "No Results"
Else
    Debug.Print minpos
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you find the row number `RowOfMin` of the minimal value in a range `RangeToSearch`:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FindMinimum()
    Dim RangeToSearch As Range
    Set RangeToSearch = Worksheets("Berechnung").Columns("F")

    Dim RowOfMin As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        RowOfMin = .Match(.Min(RangeToSearch), RangeToSearch, 0)
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    If RowOfMin = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "No number values in column F"
    Else
        Debug.Print RowOfMin
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that you must avoid converting the minimum value into another datatype (e.g. by writing it into a variable) and instead use it directly for the `.Match` otherwise you will run into floating point issues.